# LibGDX persist actors while switching screens?

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I'm making a game in LibGDX and I have a couple of menu screens using the scene2d ui. 
I have one MenuBaseScreen super class that sets up the default actors required for each screen. Then i have a MainMenu, Options etc screens that each inherit from MenuBaseScreen.
In each of the screens there is a parallax background that keeps going from right to left. 
This parallax background gets instantiated in the MenuBaseScreen.

Now the problem with this is that each time I switch screen there is a quick lag because the 
background have to get re-instantiated and added to the stage again since each subclass calls the super constructor where all of this happens.

So I was wondering if there is a way to persist this image and its animation while switching screens?

Of course I could just replace all the actors except my background and just have one screen instead of many. But I think that approach is kind of clunky and makes for error prone code.

Thank you.

Comment: Keep it in another class so it's not recreated every time.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the actors/components needed part of the MenuBaseScreen as `static` that are used in multiple screens. Also you might want to look at using the Screen interface already in libGDX with the Game class for your ApplicationListener class. More info [here](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/ScreenAndGameClasses).

Comment: No! This is really bad advise. First of all, static variables on Android are problematic as they may survive app restarts, leading to hard to track down bugs. Secondly, the wiki you link to is not the official wiki, horribly outdated, and often factually wrong. OP, you want to look into AssetManager for keeping your assets alive across screens.