# LibGDX share background between screens

Tags: java, libgdx

I am using LibGDX to make a game and currently i'm working on the main menu. Right now, i have a list of sprites that are rendered and animated across the screen in the main menu. I want to have sub menus share this background without the sprites getting reset to their original position. So all of these menus should use the same animated background.

The background should stay the same and not "reset" when navigating through the menu like this:

Main Menu > Play Game > Level Select

Main Menu > Settings > Video Settings

Currently i have a `MainMenu` class that initializes the sprites and all other menus extend that class, but since they all call `super()` the background gets reset. What would be a good way of achieving this animated background?

This is basically the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231029/libgdx-persist-actors-while-switching-screens), but that one doesn't have any good answers.

Comment: how complex is your game? If its not too complex, maybe just don't change screens at all. You could manage you game states on the same screen. You show the menu on top of the game. The game is paused and resumes when you close the menu.

Comment: I thought about doing it like this but i think it could get messy rather quickly. Right now the game is pretty simple, but i dont want to have to change everything again when it gets more complicated

Comment: If your background is an object you could pass it around between the different screens when you instantiate them. This would save its state so it does not need to reset and you avoid making it static.

Comment: The background consists of a TiledMap and multiple lists of sprites so i dont really want to pass all of that around to each screen

Comment: Whats the harm? You are going to need it all at some point anyway. And you are not creating the object every time, you are just passing a reference to a block of memory in the heap space.

Comment: Ok, i will try doing it like that then. thanks for the help!